# terminal lockup

Tags: command-line

my terminal looks ok, takes the first line of text but will not except any text after the enter key is pressed, it asks for password but, the prompt remains static as I try to input my password and only responds to the enter command by asking again for the password.

Comment: invisible password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter your complete password, you won't be shown any characters- no not even `*`s and then press enter.